# How can I get the month number (not month name) from a date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get the month number in sql? I use the following code but it returns the month name.

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use datepart function with m extension.

```
SELECT DATEPART(m, getdate())
```

Comment: It is interesting to see that both `m` and `mm` formats return month number.

Answer (score 16):

Use the month function - `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())`

Comment: This works exactly as the OP requested and in my opinion is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
DATEPART(mm,getdate());
```

Comment: It is interesting to see that both `m` and `mm` formats return month number. This thread has two absolutely correct answers :)

Answer (score 3):

You want [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
select datepart(mm, getdate())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this to pad the month number

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + RTRIM( CAST( DATEPART( MONTH, GETDATE() ) AS varchar(2)) ) , 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return with two char in case of Jan-Sep:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(MONTH(GETDATE())) = 1 THEN '0' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
WHEN LEN(MONTH(GETDATE())) = 2 THEN CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) END
```

Answer (score -3):

We can use the SQL Function: MONTH(DATE) as a parameter. It will return the month number.

Comment: The `MONTH` function was already posted as an answer to this question 10 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704264/73226