# Why is there a space when concatenating varchars in this SQL 2008 query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was tasked with setting up a control number based on month and date that are passed into a stored procedure.  I pass a month and a year but I need to pad the month so that 1-9 show up as 01-09 as the number of characters must stay the same for import.  My result should yield Z_0+month+year as a 9 character field, such as Z_0201901 for January 2019.

I used this post [How can I get the month number (not month name) from a date in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704186/how-can-i-get-the-month-number-not-month-name-from-a-date-in-sql-server) to pad the 0's in month.  Specifically `SELECT RIGHT('00' + RTRIM( CAST( DATEPART( MONTH, GETDATE() ) AS varchar(2)) ) , 2)`.

My issues is that I somehow get a space inserted when I concatenate a month and a year even though each variable individually does NOT include a space.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Mon char(3),
        @Year char(6)

SET @Mon = '5'
SET @Year = '2019'

SET @Mon = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Mon as varchar(2))), 2)
SET @Year = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Year AS varchar(4))), 5)
SELECT @Year
SELECT @Mon
SELECT @Year+@Mon

SELECT 'Z_' + @Year + @Mon ;
```

Expected result is that I would get `Z_0201905` but I get `Z_02019 05`.
Initially I thought it is because I declared @Mon as char(3) but even changing that to char(2) has the same behavior.
Changing @Year to char(5) and adding a 0 to `SELECT 'Z_0' + @Year + @Mon;` yields the same result.
Setting @Mon variable to something higher than 9, such as 12, still yields the same result of having a space.

Running `SELECT @@VERSION` yields: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64)   Apr  3 2015 14:50:02   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)`

I tried using CONCAT but through Stack Overflow found that the function isn't available until SQL Server 2012.

What is causing the space?  It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Effectively your question boils down to the difference between using char and varchar for you datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declare `@Year` as `char(6)`. Thus it will always have 6 characters. Any characters not used when setting the string will be padded with white spaces. Thus your `@Year` string becomes '02019 ' when you set it to '02019'. Declare it as `char(5)` or a `varchar`. Then the value would be '02019' so that when the strings are concatenated you will end up with your desired 'Z_0201905'.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
DECLARE @Mon char(2),
        @Year char(5)
```

I've updated your script and changed the output so you can see what is going on.

```
DECLARE @Mon char(3),
        @Year char(6)

SET @Mon = '5'
SET @Year = '2019'

SET @Mon = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Mon as varchar(2))), 2)
SET @Year = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Year AS varchar(4))), 5)
--SELECT @Year
--SELECT @Mon
--SELECT @Year+@Mon
SELECT 'Z_' + @Year + @Mon ;
SELECT 'Z_' + '-->' + @Year + '<-- -->' + @Mon + '<--' as [has extra spaces] ;

go

DECLARE @Mon char(2),
        @Year char(5)

SET @Mon = '5'
SET @Year = '2019'

SET @Mon = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Mon as varchar(2))), 2)
SET @Year = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Year AS varchar(4))), 5)
--SELECT @Year
--SELECT @Mon
--SELECT @Year+@Mon
SELECT 'Z_' + @Year + @Mon ;
SELECT 'Z_' + '-->' + @Year + '<-- -->' + @Mon + '<--' as [no extra spaces] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Mon varchar(3),
        @Year varchar(5)

SET @Mon = '5'
SET @Year = '2019'

SET @Mon = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Mon as varchar(2))), 2)
SET @Year = RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(@Year AS varchar(4))), 5)
SELECT @Year
SELECT @Mon
SELECT @Year+@Mon

SELECT 'Z_' + @Year + @Mon ;
```